# Inline javascript different if IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, href

I have a lightbox that works in all browsers except IE. So, I just want IE to open the information in a new window. How do I change this href to a website address if using IE?

From the header:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var htmlblock = 'html to appear in lightbox/new window';
</script>
```

And from the body:

```
<a id="contact-link" href="javascript:lightbox(htmlblock);">
    <div id="contact-button">
        Link to open lightbox/new window
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You could just make it work in IE. Not hard, especially in IE9 and 10 that seem to support JavaScript better than Firefox in places...

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but that's not what I asked for. I really want to know how to change the href to a link depending on the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. But lightbox should work fine in IE.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var htmlblock = 'html to appear in lightbox/new window';
</script>

<![IF IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openLightbox() {
        // do ie stuff;
    }
</script>
<![endif]>

<![if !IE]>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function openLightbox() {
        lightbox(htmlblock);
    }

</script>
<![endif]>
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="contact-link" href="javascript:openLightbox();">
    <div id="contact-button">
        Link to open lightbox/new window
    </div>
</a>
```

*note: you should not use `div` inside an `a` tag*